# Can You Verify an iOS UUID Through iCloud via PHP

Tags: php, ios, icloud, uuid

I have not worked with iCloud but have been looking through some of the documentation. I am simply trying to figure out if it is possible to send a UUID & an App ID (?) to iCloud and have iCloud tell me if it the pair is legitimate - if the UUID actually belongs to a user of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to connect to iCloud via anything else than the app itself. You can't even get the user's iCloud email on the app.

Answer (score 1):

After May 1st you won't have access the the UUID of a device.  What you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: My understanding is that UDID won't be accessible. UUID (NSUUID) will be fine.